# OpenAL seems to ignore sound attentuation/orientation for long sounds

Tags: c#, opentk, openal

I don't know how else to describe it in the title, sorry.

My sound engine currently works perfectly with listener positioning and sound positioning to create the attentuation and panning effects.  At least, for short sounds.

I converted an .mp3 to .wav to test out playing a song from a specific point, but suddenly OpenAL ignores that the sound and the listener are not at the same place and just plays the song at full volume right in the center.

Has anyone ever had this problem before?  If so, just *what* is the problem?

EDIT:
If it helps, the song is stereo and the sounds are mono, all at 16 bits per sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WAV can also be stereo and positioning gets ignored in that case; you'll need to flatten that to mono and then everything should work like you want.